# Typescript: getting right-hand side arithmetic error

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am getting an error stating the following when I attempt to do simple arithmetic in TS:

```
The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
```

I am not sure what I am doing incorrect here as it seems to be basic arithmetic.
I'd assume it's the correct type since I set it to CSSStyleDecleration:

```
  const computedNode = window.getComputedStyle(coversContainer) as CSSStyleDeclaration;
  const coversContainerHeight = (computedNode.height - (computedNode.paddingTop + computedNode.paddingBottom));
```

Comment: The height and padding are declared as `string` (e.g. `10px`). Hence the error

Comment: just use `parseInt` on each property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, Typescript try to warn you: Do not do some math with strings?

```js
  // computedNode's properties are strings
  const computedNode = {
    height: '20px',
    paddingTop: '8px', 
    paddingBottom: '8px'
  }
  
  const coversContainerHeight = (computedNode.height - (computedNode.paddingTop + computedNode.paddingBottom));
```